# What does "Thanks for having me" mean?

Tags: meaning

It seems to be used like "Thanks for inviting me". But it sounds like "Thank me, cause I was there".

Looking for a better explanation and situations it should be used in.

Comment: It's ok, really. It mesns "thank you for having me over to your house" or, in other words, thanks for inviting me" ( or for putting up with me even though I showed up uninvited)

Comment: In my opinion, "Thanks for having me" is pretty much equivalent in meaning to "Thanks for your hospitality" or "Thanks for inviting me as your guest". (I often hear interviewees using this form of words to thank the host/presenter of a radio show   at the end of their interview.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can "have someone for dinner" or "have someone on your show" or "have someone over for coffee" or "have someone in for a chat." In other words, "having someone" means inviting + welcoming + being hospitable.

Thus: "thanks for having me" means thanks for any of those hospitable things. It in no way denotes or implies that the listener should thank the speaker for showing up. "Thanks for" + something is always an expression of appreciation, and never a demand for such.

It can be used in any situation that is friendly and somewhat social. That is, we wouldn't use it in purely business or professional situations.

Comment: I think @Brain Hitchcock has a great alternative expression too. "Thanks for having me over.." clears the cloud. Its much clearer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

"Thank you for having me" is a useful parting phrase in social situations where you are a first-time guest or not close to the host. Following it with a compliment is good form.

On radio interview programs, this is the usual response to the host welcoming the guest. The problem with this phrase is that it can sound a bit subservient or insincere. Often the guest is a busy person who is taking time out of his or her schedule to be interviewed. When this is the case, thanks are more logically offered to the guest. A generic "Good to be with you" is gracious without creating the peculiar situation of expressing gratitude to someone who is asking you to do them a favor.

Answer (score -1):

To me, it sounds like an incomplete sentence.  If one is thanking someone for something, why not be specific ie. "thanks for having me on your show" or "thanks for having me over for lunch" etc.

Comment: Because what you are thanking them for is usually clear from the context.  If you want to emphasize one part what you are thanking them for you might say, e.g. "Thanks for having me, and especially, thanks for giving me the recipe for the soufflé."

Comment: @user127380  Welcome.  May I invite you to earn yourself an award by clicking 'help' and reading through the conventions.

Comment: @user127380: no, it's just an idiom of the English language. The listener will know what the speaker meant, whether it's a dinner party or a house stay or whatever. Being more specific would sound stilted, as the phrase is used in an informal context.